# Creating a Geth Genesis File from Parity Chain Spec

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, parity, genesis, chainspec

I have a parity chain spec file that I'm running on several nodes in a private network.  I need to run a geth node and connect it to this private network.

How do I use this chain spec file to connect geth to the private network?

Comment: As far as I know there is not tool to convert a parity chain spec into a valid geth genesis json. What you could do is creating the geth genesis first and generate a valid parity chain spec afterwards.

Comment: I did not ask for a tool.  My question was not about converting anything.  My question was: "how do I use this chain spec file to connect geth to the private network?"

Comment: Oh I see: It's not possible since geth expects another format.

Comment: Right.  And there must be some way to take the information in one format it and re-format it for the other.  My question is how to do that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with creating private ethereum networks with parity but am familiar with creating geth networks. Can you post the parity configuration file?

Comment: @0xcaff Do you mean the chain spec .json file?  No I can't.  If you mean the config file, I'm not suing one.  I'm using command line options.  But again: the Parity nodes aren't the problem.  What I need is help getting geth on the same network.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After months of research, I determined that there is not any way to do this at present.  Geth is not configurable enough to accommodate Parity chain spec parameters (unless you are only changing the same parameters that exist in a Geth genesis file).

Answer (score 1):

[keorn's chain spec converter](https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec) is a usefull tool to convert geth chain specs, but I do not know of any tool working the other way around.

It's best to start with a working set of genesis files and chain specs for both clients. Since this question keeps coming up, I created a [working chainspec for both clients](https://github.com/5chdn/crossclient-chainspec):

```
git clone https://github.com/5chdn/crossclient-chainspec
cd crossclient-chainspec
```

Geth:

```
$ geth init --datadir ~/.ethereum/crossclient geth.json
$ geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/crossclient --networkid 1337 --port 31333 --rpcport 8538
```

Parity:

```
$ parity --chain parity.json --port 31337 --jsonrpc-port 8539
```

Comment: You said "It's best to start with a working set of genesis files and chain specs for both clients." but that's the whole issue. The question is how to make that happen?  In this iteration of the question, I am asking how to convert the parity chain spec to a working geth genesis file.  Your answer is probably useful for people with a different problem, or with a different question, but my problem is not that I don't have both types of files, and my question is specifically how to use a chain spec file (parity) and use its data to get a geth node on the network.